# How does AutoHotKey determine if a copied string is a number?

Tags: autohotkey

The following **AutoHotKey** snippet is supposed to:

1. Verify if copied string is a number
2. If so, search for that number in a website and in Windows Search.

Nothing happens.  The If's expression is not seeing integers and bypasses code.

Any ideas?

```
Send ^c
sss = ClipBoard

if sss is integer
{
    Run, https://sd.borschow.com:8443/SREdit.jsp?id=%sss%
    Run, search-ms:query=%sss%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text copy usually isn't as fast as AHK executes the subsequent code. That is, you need to wait for the clipboard to be updated:

```
F9::
    oldClip := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait
    clip := Clipboard
    if clip is integer
    {
        msgbox, integer
    }
    else
    {
        msgbox, not an integer
    }
    Clipboard := oldClip
    ; we better make that empty, since it could contain sensitive data
    oldClip := "" 
return
```

Best practice is to store the clipboard, empty it, trigger the copy, and wait for the clipboard to contain something. And finally, restore the old clipboard if you don't need the contents anymore.